# MySQL 5.6 - Database is running, but no Socket file

Tags: mysql, sockets, rhel6, mysql-5.6, mysqladmin

I am able to connect to mysql database and query it. But, I am NOT able to find the socket file.

```
$ps -ef|grep mysql
mysql    31408 30874  0 18:46 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe     --defaults-file=/mysql/admin/ofile/TEST1.cnf

mysql    31959 31408  0 18:46 pts/1    00:00:01 /usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-    file=/mysql/admin/ofile/TEST1.cnf --basedir=/usr --    datadir=/mysql01data/TEST1/data --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-    error=/mysql/admin/TEST1/errors/mysqld_safe.err --pid-    file=/mysql/admin/TEST1/run/mysqld_safe.pid
```

Here is my socket file entry in TEST1.cnf:

```
$ cat /mysql/admin/ofile/TEST1.cnf|grep sock
socket                            = /mysql/admin/TEST1/run/TEST1.sock
```

The corresponding directory only contains pid file. There is no socket file.

```
-sh-4.1$ cd /mysql/admin/TEST1/run
-sh-4.1$ ls -lrt
total 4
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 6 Apr 29 18:46 mysqld_safe.pid
```

This is the MySQL 5.6 version I installed through RPM's on RHEL 6.5. I have my old custom scripts which uses socket file to connect to the database.

So, I am wondering how I can use the socket file to connect to the database? Why the socket file is not created by default?

Comment: you can find socket file under mysql database directory

Comment: Does `sudo lsof -a -U -p $(pgrep -d, -f /usr/sbin/mysqld)` provide any useful information?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes, I do see socket file created in /var/lib/mysql. But, why the socket file is not obeying my 'socket' parameter in the conf file? `-sh-4.1$ lsof -a -U -p $(pgrep -d, -f /usr/sbin/mysqld) COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE SIZE/OFF NAME mysqld 5042 mysql 20u unix 0t0 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: Is it configured in the `[mysqld]` section of the config file?  Is there only one entry?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  The socket parameter is in the [client] section. I changed it to [mysqld] section now and restarted mysqld. Now the socket file is created in the custom path instead of default path. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your best bet would be to put it in both, particularly if there's ever chance of a client also using that same `my.cnf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket file for a running instance of MySQL Server should be something that can be found with this shell command:

sudo lsof -a -U -p $(pgrep -d, -f /path/to/your/running/mysqld)

One possible cause of being unable to find the socket file would be if it had been deleted after the server was started.  In that case the above command should work, and show something like `(deleted)` after the path.

That was my original assumption on this question... but here the issue was a configuration oversight.  The "defaults file," commonly called `my.cnf` contains multiple sections.  The `[client]` section configures client utilities, like `mysql` and `mysqldump`, while the `[mysqld]` section configures the server daemon.  If the `socket` directive isn't in the appropriate section, the server (and/or client utilities) will look in the location compiled in by default, with `/tmp/mysql.sock` or `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` being a couple of examples of common default locations.